# I need to create List<a> include List<t> with in it. Anyone can help for this

Tags: c#, list

I have a set of data that have duplication because of joining to another table. I need to remove the duplicate and add to another List and each of that element include a list of some element.

As example :

[image]

I need to insert this data to the list: 
`List<ExistingQuestionDTO> existingQuestions = new List<ExistingQuestionDTO>();`

```
public class ExistingQuestionDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string QuestionTitle { get; set; }
    public string SurveyTitle { get; set; }
    public int SurveyId { get; set; }
    public string OptionType { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

I took this data to below List:
`IEnumerable<ExistingQuestionSpResult> existingQuestionSpResults`

and try to make an list using below algorithm. But it wont give an expected result.

```
private IEnumerable<ExistingQuestionDTO> MakeExistingQuestionSearchableDTO(
    IEnumerable<ExistingQuestionSpResult> existingQuestionSpResults)
{
    int previousQuestionId = 0;
    List<Tag> exitingTags = new List<Tag>();
    List<Tag> newTags = new List<Tag>();
    List<ExistingQuestionDTO> existingQuestions = new List<ExistingQuestionDTO>();
    ExistingQuestionDTO previousExistingQuestionDTO = new ExistingQuestionDTO();

    foreach (var questionSpResult in existingQuestionSpResults)
    {
        if (questionSpResult.QuestionId == previousQuestionId || 
            previousQuestionId == 0)
        {
            //Adding new tag if questionId exist for existing tag
            if (!(newTags.Count == 0))
            {
                exitingTags.AddRange(newTags);
                //Clear newTags array here...
                newTags.Clear();
            }

            //Add Tags for same array.
            if (!(questionSpResult.ColumnName == "NULL"))
            {
                Tag tag = new Tag
                {
                    TagId = (Guid)questionSpResult.TagId,
                    TagName = questionSpResult.ColumnName
                };
                exitingTags.Add(tag);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Add Tags for new array with Other Items too...
            exitingTags.Clear();
            newTags.Clear();

            if (!(questionSpResult.ColumnName == "NULL"))
            {
                Tag tag = new Tag
                {
                    TagId = (Guid)questionSpResult.TagId,
                    TagName = questionSpResult.ColumnName
                };
                newTags.Add(tag);
            }
        }

        ExistingQuestionDTO existingQuestionDTO = new ExistingQuestionDTO
        {
            Id = questionSpResult.Id,
            QuestionId = questionSpResult.QuestionId,
            QuestionTitle = questionSpResult.QuestionTitle,
            SurveyId = questionSpResult.SurveyId,
            SurveyTitle = questionSpResult.SurveyTitle,
            OptionType = questionSpResult.OptionType,
            Tags = exitingTags.Count != 0 ? exitingTags : newTags
        };

        if (questionSpResult.QuestionId == previousQuestionId)
        {
            //Update Tag in relevant node...
            //existingQuestions.RemoveAt((int)questionSpResult.QuestionId - 1);
            //existingQuestions.Remove(previousExistingQuestionDTO);
            //existingQuestions.Add(existingQuestionDTO);
            //existingQuestions.Insert(((int)questionSpResult.QuestionId - 1), 
            //    existingQuestionDTO);

            var foundQuestion = existingQuestions.Find(a => 
                a.QuestionId == questionSpResult.QuestionId);
            foundQuestion.Tags = exitingTags;
            existingQuestions[(int)questionSpResult.QuestionId - 1] = foundQuestion;
        }
        else
        {
            existingQuestions.Add(existingQuestionDTO);
        }

        previousQuestionId = questionSpResult.QuestionId;
        previousExistingQuestionDTO = existingQuestionDTO;
    }

    IEnumerable<ExistingQuestionDTO> exitingQuestionList = existingQuestions;
    return exitingQuestionList;
}
```

Can somebody show me what went wrong here ?

QuestionId 3 should have Tags.count => 2. But for here it gives 17. I am so confused.

Comment: FYI, there is a "not equals" operator that allows you to do `if (a != b)` instead of `if (!(a == b))` (it's a little more readable)

Comment: "enter image description here" is an instruction for you to follow. Please do so, now.

Answer (score 0):

Since redundancy reason is not mentioned properly and row-wise its completely unique except for questionid 3 where the status has both critical and important. So, first, you have to add a filter for the same and see if you are getting completely unique results or not.